# Accordion icons not appear

Tags: jquery, css

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code? There is no + icon appear.

What do I have:

**JS (jQuery):**

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
      $("#accordion").accordion({
        icons: icons,
        collapsible: true,
        active: false,
        heightStyle: "content"
      });
      var icons = {
        header: "ui-icon-circle-plus",
        activeHeader: "ui-icon-circle-minus"
      };

    });
  });
</script>
```

**CSS:**

```
.ui-icon-circle-plus {
    background-color:red;
    background-size:20px;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
}
```

Comment: There is nothing in the code you have shown that would make a `+` symbol magically appear. If you are using JQuery Mobile then tag your question as such and show us how you are including the library

Comment: I have removed the library name from title as it is not required due to presence of tags, improved code block formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to define your `icons` object before you use it in the accordion setup:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     var icons = {
      header: "ui-icon-circle-plus",
      activeHeader: "ui-icon-circle-minus"
    };

     $("#accordion").accordion({
      icons: icons,
      collapsible: true,
      active: false,
      heightStyle: "content"
    });

  });
```

Also, by defining css content in your own ui-icon-circle-plus class, you're overwriting some of the styles in the class. Specifically, setting a background-color will cover up an image. Here's what I did to your css to make it display correctly:

```
.ui-icon-circle-plus {
    <!--background-color:red;-->
    background-size:20px;
    width:18px;
    height:20px;
}
```

And here's the working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/fmug178v/3/

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, it was my fault to changing those two part of the js script. However, I use completely the same html, js, css in here: https://jsfiddle.net/MaWsm/19/ works perfectly. In my browsers, there is not any icons appear. When I use jQuery theme, it also works.  Do you have any idea, what can be the problem?

Comment: Yeah, in jsfiddle, you want to separate your JavaScript (this goes in the bottom left panel) from the HTML (this goes in the top left panel). The external sources/scripts should be included by adding their URLs as "External Resources" in the left menu rather than as <script> or <link> tags in your HTML. I adjusted your jsfiddle and the icons are working for me now: https://jsfiddle.net/MaWsm/20/  Hope that helps!

Comment: In jsfiddle it works perfectly for me as well, but I copied the codes and put into separate html, css, and js files. There's still no icons, however when I use the jQuery themes than it works. I do not understand why I need to use  themes css files to make those icons appear.

Comment: The icons are built into those jquery theme libraries. Without referencing those, the icons don't exist in your project.